# Why I can save maximum 370 characters into a file from a string with PHP?

Tags: php, string, file, summernote, php-7.2

I have some problems with saving some strings into a `.txt` file.
I have a `textarea` on my client side form, which is used with [summernote](https://summernote.org/) and I sent the form with `POST` to my server, which got it, doesn't matter, how long is the text, I know, because I print it. But, at the moment when I want to save it to a `.txt` file then I only can save 369-370 characters! If there is more then the `PHP` ignore it, and doesn't save anything. This is how I save it:

```
fwrite($file, iconv('utf-8','ISO-8859-2',$text."\r\n"));
```

**UPDATE**
I open the file with:

```
$file = fopen("file.txt","a") or die ('<h1 class="dangermsg"> <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>Error msg!</h1>');
```

How can I save more characters, or how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Are you running PHP on Windows or Linux and what mode are you `fopen`ing `$file` with?

Comment: @lufc I open it with `append`, and I'm on `Localhost via UNIX socket ` according to the hosting provider information.

Comment: Are you sure that `iconv()` is not truncating the file because of an illegal character? Have you tried writing `$text` to the file without using `iconv()`? You should also use `PHP_EOL` instead of `\r\n`.

Comment: @lufc Without the `iconv()` I got some strange encoding problems, but, only that, The size problem remains. The `\r\n` will change, thank's for the warning.

Comment: Try mode `ab` for binary append.

Comment: @lufc Thanks! this is working! Thank you! This is amazing! Send me as an answer and I will accept it!

Comment: No problem, I posted it for other users. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with text encoding it's usually safer to open the file in binary mode by adding `b` to your mode, so in this case use `ab` instead of `a`.

Per the docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

> If you do not specify the 'b' flag when working with binary files, you may experience strange problems with your data, including broken image files and strange problems with \r\n characters.
>
> For portability, it is strongly recommended that you always use the 'b' flag when opening files with fopen().
>
> It is also strongly recommended that you re-write code that uses or relies upon the 't' mode so that it uses the correct line endings and 'b' mode instead.

Also use `PHP_EOL` constant instead of `\r\n`, this allows for cross-OS functionality.